# Electron.js multiple accelerators

Tags: electron

Let's see this piece of code for an Electron menu template:

```
const menu = [
  {
    label: "foo"
    submenu: [
      {
        label: "bar",
        accelerator: "Control+B"
      {
    ]
  }
]
```

How do I register multiple accelerators for the same menu item?

**Real world example:** I want to register both `F3` and `Control+F` for the Find in page function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unfortunate answer as of now (Electron 5.0.7) is that you can't (natively). This is a tracked [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5256).

One commenter suggested this workaround:

> ```
> // it's not possible to add multiple accelerators
> // so need to do this the oldschool way
> document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
>     if (process.platform === 'darwin' && event.metaKey && event.shiftKey) {
>         if (event.keyCode === 221/* ] */) {
>             nextConversation();
>         }
>
>       if (event.keyCode === 219/* [ */) {
>             previousConversation();
>         }
>     }
> });
> ```

Someone else suggested to use the [`electron-localshortcut`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-localshortcut) module to work around this.

Answer (score 3):

One way of solving this at least in the later versions of Electron is to add an additional invisible menu item, with the same function but different accelerator:

```js
const menu = [
  {
    label: "foo"
    submenu: [
      {
        label: "bar",
        accelerator: "Control+B"
      },
      {
        label: "bar (invisible)",
        accelerator: "Control+C",
        visible: false,   
        acceleratorWorksWhenHidden: true
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

This will work exactly the same, but not show and with `acceleratorWorksWhenHidden` will still listen to the shortcut.